# Why is the time complexity of this problem only consider the previous recursive call and not the entire problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Here we have a box that is 4 * 7 and it can be filled with rectangles that are either 1 * 2 or 2 * 1. This depiction is from the book *Competitive Programmer's Handbook*.

[image]

To solve this problem most efficiently, the book mentions using the parts that can be in a particular row:

[image]

Since there are 4 things in this set, the maximum unique rows we can have is 4^m, where m is the number of columns. From each constructed row, we construct the next row such that it is valid. Valid means we cannot have vertical fragments out of order. Only if all vertical "caps" in the top row correspond to vertical "cups" in the bottom row and vice versa is the solution valid. (Obviously for the horizontal fragments, their construction is restricted in row creation itself, so it is not possible for there to be inter-row discrepancy here.)

The book then says this:

> Since a row consists of m characters and there are four choices for
>   each character, the number of distinct rows is at most 4^m. Thus, the
>   time complexity of the solution is O(n4^{2m}) because we can go through
>   the O(4^m) possible states for each row, and for each state, there are
>   O(4^m) possible states for the previous row.

Everything is fine until the last phrase, "there are O(4^m) possible states for the previous row." Why do we only consider the previous row? There are more rows, and this time complexity should consider the entire problem, not just the previous row, right?

Here is my ad hoc C++ implementation for 2 by n matrix, which would not work in this case, but I was trying to abstract it:

```cpp
int ways[251];

int f(int n){
    if (ways[n] != 1) return ways[n];
    return (ways[n] = f(n-1) + f(n-2));
}

int main(){
    ways[0] = 1;
    ways[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 250; i++){
        ways[i] = -1;
        cout << f(250) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Because we assume that previous rows except last two are already completely filled (that's called dynamic programming with profile, where profile is mask of last two rows)

Comment: @J.S.  So for each row, we only consider the previous row. That is if we have 4 rows, and we want to figure out how many ways there are to fill the 3rd row, we compare a certain fixed state of the 2nd row and see how many ways we can fill in the 3rd. But what about other states of the 2nd row? We have to calculate those separately too right?

Comment: The main idea is that you calculate number of possible states for each mask. So when you fill the third row, for each mask you know number of ways you can reach it (that includes how you fill first and second rows) and then you put new rectangles and add this value to the new mask with it. This is how you get new values. When you fully filled third row, you're not interested in masks containing it anymore, but you know values for all masks of the fourth row and you add the fifth row to all the masks.

Comment: @J.S. Ok. So the O(n) comes from the fact that we are doing this n times(number of rows). The first O(4^m) comes from the fact that each row has 4^m possibilities at the most so we assume all of them. The second 4^m comes from the previous row of which you have to go through all the arrangements again. 1) Is this correct? 2) What is a mask? Just the states of a row, like what they can have? 3) What do you do for the first row? You can't use the previous row here, right? Thanks for your help so far. Feel free to include this stuff in an answer.

Comment: 1) Maybe I don't understand what you mean, but `O(4^n)` comes from that we must iterate over all 2^n possibilities of filling `k-1`th row and `k`th row and yep, we should iterate over all of them. 2) Yep. 3) For the first row you have `d[0] = 1`, we can assume that it is what we got from the previous row (0 means that none of the first row cells have been already occupied).

Comment: @J.S. Sorry yeah, I've been thinking about this a lot this way like a tree with 4^m children: we find all possibilities of row 1 (4^m), and then from each of those 4^m states we get to another 4^m masks for row 2 and so on. So that's why I thought it was only O(n*4^m) without 4^2. What is wrong with my presumptions?