# Why can we replace horizontal and bottom vertical fragments by using single box when filling in a counting tiles map?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Here we have a box that is 4 * 7 and it can be filled with rectangles that are either 1 * 2 or 2 * 1. This depiction is from the book *Competitive Programmer's Handbook*.

[image]

To solve this problem most efficiently, the book mentions using the parts that can be in a particular row:

[image]

Since there are 4 things in this set, the maximum unique rows we can have is 4^m, where m is the number of columns. From each constructed row, we construct the next row such that it is valid. Valid means we cannot have vertical fragments out of order. Only if all vertical "caps" in the top row correspond to vertical "cups" in the bottom row and vice versa is the solution valid. (Obviously for the horizontal fragments, their construction is restricted in row creation itself, so it is not possible for there to be inter-row discrepancy here.)

The book then mysteriously says this:

> It is possible to make the solution more efficient by using a more
>   compact representation for the rows. It turns out that it is
>   sufficient to know which columns of the previous row contain the upper
>   square of a vertical tile. Thus, we can represent a row using only
>   characters upper square of a vertical tile and □, where □ is a combination of characters lower vertical square, left horizontal square and right horizontal square.
>   Using this representation, there are only 2^m distinct rows and the
>   time complexity is O(n2^(2m)).

Why does this simple square work? How would you know if there is a horizontal box underneath the top vertical fragment? How would you know left and right horizontal fragments are aligned? It breaks my mind why this is possible. Does anyone know?

Here is my ad hoc C++ implementation for 2 by n matrix, which would not work in this case, but I was trying to abstract it:

```cpp
int ways[251];

int f(int n){
    if (ways[n] != 1) return ways[n];
    return (ways[n] = f(n-1) + f(n-2));
}

int main(){
    ways[0] = 1;
    ways[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 250; i++){
        ways[i] = -1;
        cout << f(250) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57020553 (except for the title)?

Comment: @L.F. One asks about time complexity, the other asks about the construction of the solution.

Comment: It may be beneficial for you to link to that question and explain the difference.